# Add Dialogflow/Action/Assistant to routines

Tags: dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client, routines

I am trying to program **DialogFlow application** with integration to **Google Assistant** (Actions on Google). What I need is periodical execution of my script in a certain time over chosen Google Home device - I managed to do that through **Routines**.

Unfortunately the settings of Routines is not as easy as I expected (you need go through several click and typing of custom action name). Then I found that it is possible to ask the user for that in the Assistant ([Routine suggestions](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/routines)) and let him set that with fewer necessary steps.

But my implementation is not working:

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  ...
  function scheduleRoutine(agent) {
      const intent = agent.arguments.get('UPDATE_INTENT');
      agent.add(new RegisterUpdate({
        intent: intent,
        frequency: 'ROUTINES'
      }));
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  ...
  intentMap.set('setup_update', scheduleRoutine)
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

because I am using `WebhookClient` I am not able to call `conv.arguments.get('UPDATE_INTENT')` as in the example. But I can get to that part of code through fulfilment which leads to error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
     at scheduleRoutine (/user_code/index.js:71:34)
```

Have anybody already implemented **Routine suggestion with Dialogflow**?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to use RegisterUpdate from the actions-on-Google library? You cannot mix features from that library with the dialogflow-fulfillment library. They're incompatible.

If you want to use features specific to actions on Google, you must use that library for your webhook.

Comment: So do you mean to use ''const app = actionssdk()'' instead of classic webhook, right? Btw it wouldn't be necessary to do according to "Automatic discovery flow" in a link above but it is not working for me... Have experience with that?

Comment: const app = dialogflow ()